# Run failed tests from TFS post build event

Tags: visual-studio-2010, workflow-foundation-4, post-build-event, tfs-process-template

We are using TFS/VS 2010 to run Selenium tests which are scheduled in the TFS controller. After the build and tests are finished I would like to run the failed tests from that build.

Currently I am doing this by using a Windows Scheduled Task and executing a batch file which calls a powershell script which gets the latest build version (and failed tests) and then executes them (using mstest) and finally publishes the results back to build.

I just want this to happen without a windows scheduled task, it is too fickle. I believe I need to edit ProcessTemplate.xaml and add an event (InvokeProcess) to achieve this, I just can't find much on it.

Thanks in advance!